# How to pass the details from Recycler view to another activity?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

```
public class RVAdapter extends
    RecyclerView.Adapter<RVAdapter.PersonViewHolder> {    public
    List<Person> persons= Collections.emptyList(); //    private Context
    mContext; private LayoutInflater inflater;
    
    
    
        ImageLoader mImageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
    
        private static Context context;
    
    
        public RVAdapter(Context context, List<Person> persons) {
            this.persons = persons;
              this.context = context;
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        }
    
        @Override
        public PersonViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cardview,
    parent, false);
            PersonViewHolder pvh = new PersonViewHolder(v);
    
    
            return pvh;
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(PersonViewHolder holder, int postions) {
    
            Person person = persons.get(postions);
            holder.phoneName.setText(person.getKitchen_accesries());
            holder.phonePrice.setText(person.getKitchen_price());
            holder.itemView.setTag(person);
    
       if (mImageLoader == null)
               mImageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
          holder.thumbnail.setImageUrl(person.getThumbnail(), mImageLoader);
    
    
        }
    
    
        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            if (persons != null) {
                return persons.size();
            }
            return 0;
        }
    
    
        @Override
        public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
            super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
        }
    
        public static class PersonViewHolder extends RecyclerView .ViewHolder
                implements View
                .OnClickListener  {
            CardView cv;
            TextView phoneName;
            TextView phonePrice;
            public List<Person> persons;
    
    
            NetworkImageView thumbnail;
    
            PersonViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
    
                cv = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
                phoneName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.phone_name);
                phonePrice = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.phone_price);
                thumbnail = (NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
                itemView.setOnClickListener(this); //
            }
    
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view ) {
    
    
    
                Intent intent = new Intent(context,ViewActivity.class);
    
                context.startActivity(intent);
    
            }
    
    
        }
    
    
    }
```

once I  touch the the items on the recyclerview ,its go to the Viewactivity class but I cant pass the details from my list to the detailsactivity class.
I want to pass the three details from my web service to the view activity using put extra.But in the Onclick method i didnt get exact position of the items from the list.

Comment: use `RecyclerView.ViewHolder#get*Position`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following in your onclick

```
Person person =(Person)view.getTag();
String strUrl= person.getThumbnail();
String product1=person.getKitchen_accesries();
intent.putExtra("Your string key",strUrl);
intent.putExtra("Your string key",product1);
intent.putExtra("Your string key",product1);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

And then access everything in your detailsactvity as

```
phone=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_phone);
price=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_price);
product=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);

Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

String url = bundle.getString("Image");

phone.setText(bundle.getString("Your string key"));
price.setText(bundle.getString("Your string key"));

Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(url).into(product);
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to pass the three details from my web service to the view
>   activity using put extra

Because `itemView` is root view of all views from which want to access values to send other Activity. so use `view` parameter of onClick method for accessing view as:

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View view ) {
        TextView  phoneName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.phone_name);
          // do same for others
         Intent intent = new Intent(context,ViewActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("phone_name", phoneName.getText().toString());
          /// do same for other values
         context.startActivity(intent);

        }
```

Comment: Its worknig fine also can you please help to pass my images from recyclerview to detailsactvity

Comment: @SwaroopLal: Passing image is not good just pass image name or drawable id then use it in other activity  for showing image

Comment: no, you shouldn't do that, you should access your **data model**, not the `View` on which that data is presented

Comment: @pskink Yes i have model class for accessing all information using getters and setters but how can i use it inside the click method?

Comment: @SwaroopLal see my comment on your original question, why didn't you read it?

Comment: @ ρяσѕρєя K 7 i take the images in recyclerview using volley networkimage,in web service the is contain as image url,how can i pass this image url from my recyclerview to other activity?

Comment: @SwaroopLal: Ok try this `Person person =(Person)view.getTag();
String strUrl= person.getThumbnail();`  in onClick of Button

Comment: @pskink soory i didnt see your post at that time.But can you please try give some examples because now i am little confused about it.

Comment: Yes now i can add the instant of person class in my onclick method,and get the image url using the setter method.But how can retrieve this image url in Imageview contained in detailsactivity class.@ρяσѕρєяK

Answer (score 0):

Another method is to implement not using interface but runtime
Using this method, you will be able to access the object when you are implementing the click listener

> I have updated the code to set the OnClickListener on itemView, instead of holder itself. FYI, itemView is the view that held by holder, and its the view that are going to be presented in recycler view.

E.g

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(PersonViewHolder holder, int postions) {

        Person person = persons.get(postions);
        holder.phoneName.setText(person.getKitchen_accesries());
        holder.phonePrice.setText(person.getKitchen_price());
        holder.itemView.setTag(person);

        if (mImageLoader == null)
           mImageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
        holder.thumbnail.setImageUrl(person.getThumbnail(), mImageLoader);

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(View v){
            Intent i = new Intent(mContext, ViewActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("Hi",person.name);
            mContext.startActivity(i);
        });

    }
```

Comment: Soory Danny i tried your method but holder.setOnClickListener can not resolve inside my on bindviewholder

Comment: Oh sorry, my mistakes. The holder doesn't have a method of setOnClickListener. You will need to bind the click listener to the view that the holder is holding. So you should use holder.itemView.setOnClickListener